# ResultSet is a interface. How does Statement.executeQuery(String) create its object.?

Tags: java, object, interface, database-connection, resultset

I have a confusion regarding ResultSet . We know ResultSet is a interface , So it can be used as reference , but we cannot create its object . So my question is what object does Statement.executeQuery() returns ?

Comment: It returns some class that `implements ResultSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a concrete object that implements `ResultSet`.
For example, Oracle's implementation of the `Statement` interface, `OracleStatement`, returns an instance of `OracleResultSetImpl`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of the actual *implementation* class of `ResultSet`

Simply print

```
 ResultSet resultSet = ...

 System.out.println(resultSet.getClass().getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Statement` is also an interface.  So if you've got a `Statement` object, then its class is actually something else, like maybe `OracleStatement`, or `MsSqlServerStatement`, or `SybaseStatement` or whatever; depending on which JDBC driver you have.  (Actually, I kind of made up those class names - I don't know what the exact class names are, and it really doesn't matter).

Now, the version of `executeQuery` in each `Statement` implementation will be slightly different.  The one in `OracleStatement`, for example, will do some stuff and create an `OracleResultSet`.  The implementation in `MsSqlServerStatement` will do some slightly different stuff, and create a `MsSqlServerResultSet`.  I'm still making up the class names, of course, but you get the point.

You never need to worry about these classes, because the programs that you write will just use the methods listed in the interfaces.  This is exactly **what interfaces are for**.

Answer (score 0):

A ResultSet contains records which contains a set of columns. Each record contains exactly the same amount of columns, although some columns may have no value.

When you run `Statement.executeQuery()` the driver you're using to connect to your database, create that object for you. So that you can call its methods such as `next()`, `getString()`, `getInt()` etc.

To know which is returned object, you can call `rs.getClass().getName()`, assuming `rs` is the variable of your ResultSet. But you don't really need to know that. That's why you're using a Instance, and the scope of `Instance` as well.

Unless you're writing a driver library, you'll never create a `ResultSet` object, nor you have the need to do that.

Comment: _A ResultSet contains records which_ interesting story but not related to OP's question!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to gain some more understanding of interfaces and their purpose. The general idea is that an interface is a way to encapsulate similar behavior between similar type objects, and you be able to use those generalized method with any implementation.

A simple case.

> 1. `interface Animal` with `speak()` method
> 2. Two different implementations `Dragon` and `Dinosaur`

```
public interface Animal {
    void speak();
}
public class Dragon implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("I'm a Dragon!")'
    }
}
public class Dinosaur implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("I'm a Dinosaur!")'
    }
}
```

In this case there is still a case or inheritance, with `Animal` being the super type. So `Animal` can be used as a data type. And calling its method `speak()`, will result in the actually calling it's implementation specified. For example

```
Animal animal = new Dragon();
animal.speak();  // prints I am a Dragon
```

Same is the case with `ResultSet`. When you call `rs.next()`, you are not calling an empty method,

```
public interface ResultSet {
    public boolean next();
}
```

but actually a `next()` method of some `ResultSet[Impl]` that has implemented the `ResultSet` interface

```
// I'm not sure the exact concrete implementation class, Just making on up
public class ResultSetImpl implements ResultSet {
    @Override
    public boolean next() {
       return iStillHaveMore();
    }
}
```

So if `statement.executeQuery()` returns `ResultSetImpl`, then that's the `next()` method you'd be using

Comment: This analogy would have been so much better if you'd made `speak` return an interface `Speech`, implemented by (for example) `Growl` in the `Lion` class and `Fire` in the `Dragon` class.